# Centering stuff with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been working with bootstrap and for now I'm having some trouble centering the things Im creating , the first problem is not being able to center vertically a right side nav bar item , it simply gets above the center line of that nav bar , the second one is a log in form wrapped in divs with different classes that i've been trying to make it center horizontally , and why does the right side item of the nav bar has to show a dot for the unordered list when the left items do not show and it just changes the class of the div. If possible i would like to have some help on this.

[image]
the code here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Member area</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- NAV BAR -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PlaceHolder</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class "navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Member Area</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--END OF NAV BAR-->

  <!-- LOG IN FORM-->
  <form action="">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="ocol-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <input type="submit" class="form-control" id="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




  </form>

  <!-- END OF LOGIN FORM-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many issues in your template.

Firstly a missing "=" sign after the class attribute in `<ul class "navbar-nav ml-auto">`

Use `offset-lg-4` instead of `col-lg-offset-4`

"`row`" should be used inside the `container` element so changed the position of container div.

Remove the text-center from `container` element

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Member area</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- NAV BAR -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PlaceHolder</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Member Area</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--END OF NAV BAR-->

  <!-- LOG IN FORM-->
  <div class="container">
    <form action="">
      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 text-center">

            <div class="">
              <label for="username">Username</label>
              <input type="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
            </div>
            <div class="">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <div class="">
              <input type="submit" class="form-control" id="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- END OF LOGIN FORM-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This comment solved everything , i didn't even notice the "=" missing , and i was wondering why the member area link was with a different color the whole time when it shouldn't. Gotta take more care with those small things , thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using two ul on navbar-collapse, try to use only one ul, and add one more empty `li` with property `flex: 1`, this empty li will grow to fill the space between the elements, pushing them to sides.